# SQL server,find distinct groups in a table

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct, relational-division

I have table

```
prdID    item     percentage
1        10         50
1        20         50
2        10         50
2        20         50
3        20         30
3        20         70
4        10         50
4        20         30
4        30         20
5        10         50
5        20         50
```

I want to fetch the distinct groups.Basically
the result set should be

```
group   item     percentage
1        10        50
1        20        50
3        20        30
3        20        70
4        10        50
4        20        30
4        30        20
```

`2` and `5` are excluded from the result as they contain exactly the same `item/percentage` values as `1`

Comment: Distinct over what set?  Why are groups 1, 3, and 4 represented in the result set but not 2 and 5?

Comment: basically product 1,2,5 have the same composition.so they are duplicates.so i need just prd 1

Comment: Why is product 1 returned, why not 2 or 5?  Is there some kind of ordering you want imposed to decide which of the duplicate groups are returned?  Also, we need to know which database engine you are using as any answer might make use of engine-specific SQL features.

Comment: This is a type of relational division query.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is query you want:

```
SELECT MIN(prdId) AS group, item, percentage
FROM <tablename>
GROUP BY item, percentage
```

This will produce the following result on your example data:

```
group   item     percentage
1        10        50
1        20        50
3        20        30
3        20        70
4        30        20
```

(I think you made a small mistake in your example output by including the two other 4's. Their (item, percentage) values are duplicates of a group 1 and a group 3).

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table_name t
inner join (
select min(prdID) as prdID
from
(
SELECT 
  table_name.prdID as prdID,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + cast(item as varchar)+'~'+cast(percentage as varchar)
    FROM table_name t2
    WHERE t2.prdID = table_name.prdID
    FOR XML PATH (''))
,1,2,'') AS Names
FROM table_name
GROUP BY table_name.prdID
)t
group by Names)R
on t.prdID=R.prdID
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9497c/1)**